# Ignoring that user needs to input a String

Tags: java

I am quite new at programming, I am in my first class, and we have a project due next week. Now, I know there are a lot of things that can be fixed in my code, but I'm trying to figure out why it won't let me input the ssn. 
This is the program when I run it so far:

---

*Current Month: 10*

*Current Week: 2*

*Number of Employees: 3*

*PROFILE FOR EMPLOYEE # 1*

*Type of Pay (Hourly (h), Salaried (s), Salaried plus Commission (c)): h*

*Name: Biff Sanchez*

*Social Security Number: Birthday Month (1-12):*

---

I can't input the Social Security Number before it asks me to input the Birthday Month. I have tried nextLine instead of next, but it doesn't change anything.

My code is below, please help. And thank you!

---

```
package payroll;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class PayrollProgram {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00");
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get current month
        System.out.print("Current Month: ");
        int currentMonth = kybd.nextInt();
        if (currentMonth < 1 || currentMonth > 12)
        {
            System.out.print("error");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //get current week
        System.out.print("Current Week: ");
        int currentWeek = kybd.nextInt();
        if (currentWeek < 1 || currentWeek > 4)
        {
            System.out.print("error");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //get number of employees
        System.out.print("Number of Employees: ");
        int numEmployee = kybd.nextInt();
        int[] list = new int[numEmployee];

        //declare variables needed for paycheck report
        //String type1 = "";
        String [] type = new String[list.length];
        String [] name = new String[list.length];
        String [] ssn = new String[list.length];
        double [] pay = new double[list.length];
        double money = 0;

        //get information for each employee
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("PROFILE FOR EMPLOYEE # " + (i + 1) + "\n");

            //get type of pay
            System.out.print("Type of Pay (Hourly (h), Salaried (s), Salaried plus Commision (c)): ");
            type[i] = kybd.next();
            if (!type[i].equals("h") && !type[i].equals("s") && !type[i].equals("c")) 
            {
                System.out.print("error");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //get name
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name[i] = kybd.next();

            //get ssn
            System.out.print("Social Security Number: ");
            ssn[i] = kybd.next();

            //get birthday month
            System.out.print("Birthday Month (1-12): ");
            int bdayMonth = kybd.nextInt();
            if (bdayMonth < 1 || bdayMonth > 12)
            {
                System.out.print("error");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //get birthday bonus week
            System.out.print("Birthday Bonus Week (1-4): ");
            int bdayWeek = kybd.nextInt();
            if (bdayWeek < 1 || bdayWeek > 4)
            {
                System.out.print("error");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            //get hourly pay (if hourly)
            if (type.equals("h"))
            {
                System.out.print("Hourly Pay:");
                double hourlyPay = kybd.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Hours worked this past week:");
                double hours = kybd.nextDouble();
                money = hourlyPay * hours;
            }

            //get salary if salaried
            else if (type.equals("s"))
            {
                System.out.print("Salary:");
                double salary = kybd.nextDouble();
                money = salary;
            }

            //get salary if salaried plus commission
            else if (type.equals("c"))
            {
                System.out.print("Salary:");
                double salary = kybd.nextDouble();
                money = salary;

                System.out.print("Sales for this past week: ");
                double salesWeek = kybd.nextDouble();

                System.out.print("Sales Commission Rate (fraction paid to employee): ");
                double commissionRate = kybd.nextDouble();

                money = (commissionRate * salesWeek) + money;

            }

            if (bdayMonth == currentMonth && bdayWeek == currentWeek)
                money = money + 100;

            System.out.print("\n");
            pay[i] = money;

            kybd.close();
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        /*
         */

        // shows final results
        System.out.print("PAYCHECK REPORT:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.print("\nEmployee:" + name[i]);
        System.out.print("\nSocial Secuirty Number:" + ssn[i]);
        System.out.print("\nPaycheck:" + df.format(pay[i]));
        System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in the input for name and not in SSN.

Change this

```
    name[i] = kybd.next();
```

to

```
    name[i] = kybd.nextLine();
```

As the input name can contain a space so you need to use nextLine here.

Comment: @user3580294 Have u used nextLine for the name or SSN ? When u enter name with space it will eat up the kybd.next for SSN also.

Comment: @user3580294 Because it's likely that the OP tried to use `nextLine` on the SSN since that's what he was having problems with.  (He is new at programming.)  That won't work, but doing it on the name will.

Comment: @ajb Right, I don't know what I was thinking. I'll delete those comments.

Comment: I changed that, and now I'm getting a problem where it won't let me input the name:
"
PROFILE FOR EMPLOYEE # 1
Type of Pay (Hourly (h), Salaried (s), Salaried plus Commission (c)): h
**Name: Social Security Number:**
"

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution without using the nextLine(), which for some reason kept giving me trouble.

```
    //get name
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String nameF = kybd.next();
    String nameL = kybd.next();
    name[i] = nameF + nameL
```